# Chrome Extension Persistent

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to learn about chrome extension development.

There I saw something like this manifest.json

```
 "background" : {
      "scripts": ["Scripts/event.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
```

Here, i am unable to understand what does  `"persistent": false` means, According to my very vague understanding, I think it deals wether the background page should run in background at all times or not.

So If **persistent is true,** It will run even when we are working on tabs? and if it is false, it will stop it won't stop the moment we leave the browser?

Comment: When it's false, the background page automatically unloads after 5 seconds of no activity, that is when no listeners were invoked for 5 seconds. Note, the background page is a separate hidden page which is not related to the web pages in any way. See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Any tips on where to find this in the documentation?

Comment: @CodyBugstein https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: tl;dr, the page above quotes "The only occasion to keep a background script persistently active is if the extension uses chrome.webRequest API to block or modify network requests. The webRequest API is incompatible with non-persistent background pages."

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422094/6908282) is a really great resource to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

*The only occasion to keep a background script persistently active is if the extension uses chrome.webRequest API to block or modify network requests. The webRequest API is incompatible with non-persistent background pages.*

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/

Comment: [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_migration/) is useful to migrate from a persistent background to non-persistent background

Comment: **Manifest V3** - Also check out [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/service-worker-lifecycle/#idle-shutdown) for manifest v3 service worker life cycle

Answer (score 1):

if your extension is doing something again and again and for more then a minute you should keep it `"persistent": true` otherwise extension will not work properly, like when you send message to background, it wont get it and neither it will get other events